# Optional<List<T>> for Empty List in Repository Layer Returns Optional.empty . How do I change it to return Optional[[]]

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, option-type

I have a JPA Query like this.

PersonRepository.java

```
public Optional<List<PersonEntity>> findByStatus(int status);
```

PersonService.java

```
System.out.println(“Optional value is ”+findByStatus(1));
```

The output is `Optional value is Optional.empty`

Now I changed my query 
PersonRepository.java

```
public List<PersonEntity> findByStatus(int status);
```

PersonService.java

```
Optional<List<PersonEntity>> optional = Optional.of(findByStatus(1));
System.out.println("Optional value is "+optional);
```

The output is   `Optional value is Optional[[]]`

In my database, there is no value for status 1 . I want my output as `Optional[[]]` for the 1st query. How do I achieve this?

Now, I want to achieve this because, whenever an `optional.get()` throws a `NoSuchElementException`, I will handle it using my Exception Controller and expose it as 404 to the REST Layer. But, when a `List<Object>` is fetched, the response is only a empty List, but `optional.get()` still throws a `NoSuchElementException`. I want to avoid this. In short, the optional fetch of  Single Entity from Repository throws `NoSuchElementException` if no value is found which is perfect. But for the optional fetch of a list of Entities which is empty is should be returned as Empty and not throw `NoSuchElementException` as it is not a 404 error. It just means that the list is empty at present.

Comment: Wy do you want an optional collection? When nothing is found the list is empty, how is `Optional.empty()` better?

Comment: @M.Deinum I have updated my requirement. Kindly take a look at it

Comment: You already get that if you don't wrap the list in an optional.

Comment: @M.Deinum Correct. Now I face issues with code standards. In one case (single Entity fetch), I need to force `Optional` as mandatory and in the other, Optional should never be allowed.

Comment: I have similar usage scenario but I got `Optional.empty` in Spring Boot `2.4.0` and `Optional[[]]` in `2.4.10`. It is really weird!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

```
 public Optional<List<PersonEntity>> findByStatus(int status);
```

doesn't make sense.

The correct signature is

```
 List<PersonEntity> findByStatus(int status);
```

if there is no PersonEntity the list will be empty.

Comment: I want to wrap List<PersonEntity> with Optional so that NPEs can be handled by default. However, if List<PersonEntity> is empty, I don't want Optional to throw a NoSuchElementException.

Comment: I don't understand? What NPE and what NoSuchElementException?

Comment: The list will never be `null` if there is nothing it will be an empty `List`.

Comment: @M.Deinum That's what I wrote in answer. Thanks for highlighting!

Comment: @SimonMartinelli I have updated my requirement so you can understand my problem better

Comment: I was reacting to the comment (and apparently you did as well :) ).

Comment: @MaruthiAdithya I only can say that this is a strange requirement and not the way it should be implemented. Exceptions are to report errors and not for controlling program logic

Comment: @SimonMartinelli I know that the approach itself is a bit strange. But the idea behind this is to avoid redundant code. See, the traditional way to handle 404 errors is to throw an EntityNotFoundException(); But this code of null check and throw EntityNotFoundException(); will keep on repeating in every package again and again.

Comment: The number zero is repeated in many classes too, again and again.  That still isn't "redundant code".

Comment: You could create a base class that is handling that with a common method to build the response instead of Excelptions

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you stop thinking technique-oriented and start thinking meaning-oriented.

By the latter, I mean : the essence of a lookup function where the user provides a precisely-known identifier and the result is expected to be at most, or exactly, one entity is that it is fundamentally different from that of a lookup function where the user provides some search criteria and any number of matching entities could be returned.

The former is where there is a *logical need* for `return null;` or for `throw new NotFoundException();` or for `return Optional.ofNullable(null);`

The latter is where there is *no logical need* for any such thing because both arrays and collections already cover for every possible number from zero to infini ... well however much you're likely to ever need.

Focusing on the essence of the functionality is way more important than focusing on particular techniques.

EDIT

And if you *absolutely want* (begs the question 'why' though) the same return type for both sorts of lookup function, then Collection<...> is the "right" option, with an empty collection denoting "Not found" in the "single entity lookup" scenario.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing different things.

```
Optional<List<PersonEntity>>
```

means that the value it holds is `empty`.

I can only assume that Spring does something like:

```
if(list == null || list.isEmpty()) {
    return Optional.empty();
}
```

In the second case that `List<PersonEntity>` is an Optional from an *empty* List.